# how to perform a single execution of a future?

Tags: flutter, dart

What I am trying to do is that by starting the app, make a request to a server and all information is saved in the database, for that I use a `FutureBuilder` that does the whole process, once finished it starts the application as normal.

The problem is that the application executes my future synchronization more than twice, causing errors with the insert to database.
the following code is a basic example of what i am trying to do and the result i am getting.

### main.dart

```
void main() => runApp(MyMaterialApp());

class MyMaterialApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    print('Running MyMaterialApp');
    return MaterialApp(
      home: SplashLoad(),
    );
  }
}

class SplashLoad extends StatefulWidget {

  @override
  _SplashLoadState createState() => _SplashLoadState();
}

class _SplashLoadState extends State<SplashLoad> {
  final apiSimulation = new ApiSimulation();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    print('SplashScreen');
    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        child: Center(
          child: FutureBuilder(
            future: apiSimulation.sincronizacion(),
            builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<int> snapshot) {
              if (snapshot.hasData) {
                return Text('load finished data:${snapshot.data}');
              }
              return CircularProgressIndicator();
            },
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

### ApiSimulation

```
class ApiSimulation {
  int number = 0;
  Future<int> synchronization()async{
    print('INIT SYNCHRONIZATION');
    await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 2));
    final data = await _getData();
    return data;
  }

  Future<int> _getData() async{
    number++;
    print('running getData$number');
    await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 2));
    return number;
  }
}
```

### console result

```
I/flutter (32404): Running MyMaterialApp
I/flutter (32404): SplashScreen
I/flutter (32404): INIT SYNCHRONIZATION
I/flutter (32404): Running MyMaterialApp
I/flutter (32404): SplashScreen
I/flutter (32404): INIT SYNCHRONIZATION
I/flutter (32404): running getData1
I/flutter (32404): running getData2
```

Sometimes reaching 4 in the value of the number

Comment: you should fetch your initial data in the ``initState`` method instead of using a future builder under the build method as any change in state will cause the widget to rebuild thus recalling the API.

Comment: @OMiShah ok, I have used initState to initialize classes or variables, but never for the future. How can I use it with CircularProgressIndicator?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what the document says

> The future must have been obtained earlier, e.g. during
> State.initState, State.didUpdateWidget, or
> State.didChangeDependencies. **It must not be created during the
> State.build or StatelessWidget**.build method call when constructing the
> FutureBuilder. If the future is created at the same time as the
> FutureBuilder, then every time the FutureBuilder's parent is rebuilt,
> **the asynchronous task will be restarted**.

```
class _SplashLoadState extends State<SplashLoad> {
  late final Future simFuture;
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    simFuture= ApiSimulation().sincronizacion(); //initiate your future here
  }
```

Within your future builder use

```
FutureBuilder(
   future: simFuture,
   builder: (ctx,snap){..},
)
```